# Testing WebApi with Fiddler POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

GET works fine. In the Controller I have this method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(Product product)
    {
        var isSaved = productService.SaveProduct(product);
        if (isSaved == true) return Ok();
        else return BadRequest(); 
    }
```

The problem is, product is null. I get to this method (via a breakpoint) but am not sure why the product is null. Here's what's in Fiddlers Composer:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
host: localhost:53882
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 54
```

And this is the Fiddler request body:

```
{
id:5,
name: Dress,
price: 39.90,
quantity:71
}
```

[image]
There's no model. It's all in the db (edmx). It works for getting a list of products, or a product by product id.

Comment: You need to show what the Product class looks like.

Comment: I would guess that your product binding does not work, Check what properties you have available and what you are passing. Check what fields are required in database.

Comment: But the product parameter comes into the method as a null. This is all before it hits the database.

Comment: @Ron can you post the raw session from fiddler? Right-click session in fidder > Copy > Session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `name` in your request body is missing the double quotes. Make sure the cases matches as your model because it is case-sensitive.

```
{
  id:5,
  Name: "Dress",
  Price: 39.90,
  Quantity:71
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue could be with contentType, you should include in the header 
Content-Type: application/json

and yes also the json you are posting   is not valid :  Name: "Dress",